# Setting up development vagrant box for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vagrant, rbenv

I'm setting up a development Rails box in Vagrant using Ansible. It's all set up and i've used Rbenv to facilitate installation of Ruby. I installed Ruby 2.1.2

When I run `rbenv global` I get `2.1.2`. When I navigate to my app directory and run `rbenv local` I get `2.1.2` and when I run `ruby -v` I get `2.1.2`. My gemfile also states `2.1.2`

However, when I run `bundle install`, I get:

> Your Ruby version is 1.8.7, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: is `bundle install` using `bundle` from `rbenv`? Sounds like its using a system gem from the system install of `ruby`.

Comment: How do I check this?

Comment: what does the output of `which bundle` say?

Comment: `/opt/vagrant_ruby/bin/bundle`

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the bundle gem using the `rbenv` `gem` command:

```
rbenv global 2.1.2

# ensure all shims for current ruby version are there
rbenv rehash

gem install bundler

# rehash again to make sure you get the `bundler` command from `rbenv`
rbenv rehash

bundle install
```

Hope this helps

Comment: When I try to run `rbenv rehash`, I get `rbenv: cannot rehash: /usr/local/rbenv/shims/.rbenv-shim exists`

Comment: well, try to just do `gem install bundler`. then `which bundler` to make sure its the `rbenv` version of it.

Comment: also, check permissions on `/usr/local/rbenv` that `rehash` error can happen if rbenv can't write to someplace that it should be able to. are you `root`?

Comment: `whoami` is reporting `vagrant`

Comment: well that explains it. run `sudo rbenv rehash`.

Comment: Why should I be running as root? Sorry, I'm not fully up on all this and am still learning my way around.

Comment: you need to check permissions for `/usr/local/rbenv` and the `directories` under it. If the directories that `rbenv` needs to write to are not writable by the `vagrant` user, then `rbenv rehash` isn't going to work.